# PYTHONPATH in PyCharm and Windows 10 Command Line

Tags: python-2.7, environment-variables, pycharm

I've created a project in Pycharm that I can successfully run and as well its unit tests. However, when I try to run pytest from the command line in the location where the tests folder is I get an error where the tests protest that it can't find objects in the given module (under test). I know that Pycharm runs certain commands before launching anything and exports the information through PYTHONPATH to make its tests work but how do I do the same thing without PyCharm?

The following shows my project structure:

```
PycharmProjects\
     ProjectFolder\
         - setup.py
         - readme.txt
         module\
             - __init__.py
             - module.py
         tests\
             - __init__.py
             - test_module.py
```

Before Pycharm runs my code, it does the following at the time when the script starts up (I got this from Settings > Console > Python Console). I don't know how to tell what is inside WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS.

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
```

However, when I run from the command line when I am at the Project Folder I get the following type of error. What gives??

```
D:\user\development\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder> pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.11, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: D:\user\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder, inifile:
collected 4 items

tests\test_module.py .F.F

================================== FAILURES ===================================
_______________________ TestModule.test_ONE ________________________

self = <tests.test_module.TestModule testMethod=test_ONE>

    def test_ONE(self):
>       someObject = module.SomeObject("someObject.log")
E       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SomeObject'

tests\test_module.py:23: AttributeError
________________________ TestModule.test_TWO _________________________

self = <tests.test_module.TestModule testMethod=test_TWO>

    def test_TWO(self):
>       someObject = module.SomeObject("someObject.log")
E       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SomeObject'

tests\test_module.py:8: AttributeError
===================== 2 failed, 2 passed in 0.14 seconds ======================
```

Comment: Is your `PYTHONPATH=D:\user\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder`? What does your `import` statement inside of `tests\test_module.py` look like for `module`? In this scenario it would need to be `from module import module`, and `SomeObject` would be a `class` inside `D:\user\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder\module\module.py`

Comment: 1). `PYTHONPATH=D:\user\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder` 2). Inside `tests\test_module.py`, the import says `import module`; 3). I tried the `from module import module` and I get the following error now in PyCharm (but the command line now works)  --- `from module import module, ImportError: cannot import name module`

Comment: Why do the two (pycharm and command line) fight with each other in terms of settings??

Comment: I'm guessing your project structure isn't set up properly in PyCharm to be compatible with how you are trying to do things on the command line. If you made `PYTHONPATH=D:\user\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder;D:\user\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder\module` and your import statement `import module` I bet it would work in both, but that's not really the correct way of doing it. Try changing your project content root `Settings | Project | Project Structure` to `D:\user\PycharmProjects\ProjectFolder`. If that doesn't work I'd probably need to see an image of your prj struct in PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the directory that has your source package/module. So if your package is at `C:\my_stuff\foo\my_package` you will want your PYTHONPATH to be `C:\my_stuff\foo`. You will also want to make sure you have `__init__.py` files in all of the directories which contain source code.

You may also need to add your python area to the `PATH` env variable. If your python.exe file is at `C:\Python27\python.exe`, you would want `C:\Python27` to be in `PATH` before any other python directories.

To set the env variable...

1. `Click Start button`
2. `Click File Explorer`
3. `Right click "This PC" -> Properties`
4. `Click Advanced system settings`
5. `Click Environment Variables...`
6. Under "User Variables for nndhawan" look for the variable `PYTHONPATH`. If it exists, `click Edit...`. If it doesn't exist, `Click New...`
7. `Variable Name: PYTHONPATH`
8. `Variable Value: C:\my_stuff\foo` Note that if you have multiple paths, they are separated with a semicolon and no spaces. Once you have multiple saved, the interface will look slightly different, but still pretty intuitive. Use `Edit` and `New` how you'd expect.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this and this didn't solve my problem. I'll update my ticket a little better.